# apache password protect specific URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, passwords

I need to password protect on specific URL, for instance anyone can access index.php but as soon as they add parameters or "GET" variables I must require valid-user.

index.php -> sweet

index.php?prev=1 -> require valid user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

Here's a solution:

```
<Location /fakeindex.php>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
  Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /pathto/htpasswd/file/passwords.secret
  AuthName This is an example auth
  Require valid-user
</Location>
<Directory /path/to/doc/root>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php
    RewriteRule .* fakeindex.php [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

This part:

```
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
  Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
```

is there to prevent a direct access to /fakeindex.php (but in fact who would like to enforce a direct access to a protected zone). It's optionnal.

The key point is that theses condition Rules detect a non empty Query string, and a request to index.php:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php
```

And that if they match the Rule:

```
RewriteRule .* fakeindex.php [L,QSA]
```

Redirect internally the request to /fakeindex.php, keeping the query string with QSA. After that the Location is applied, and authentification is on the Location.

Comment: wow! thankyou very much! one q, though - this can't be used in .htaccess because <Location is not allowed in this context...? Also, I think my actual scenario is not possible - I need to have the same file when passed nothing be world readable, but when it's passed a specific get var, it requires a valid user... this is to alleviate a whole copy of an ever changing file with one minor php change haha... thankyou so much anyway!

Answer (score -2):

You could use the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) method on the get variable eg:

```
if (isset($_GET['prev'])) {
//load password input form
}
```